# Running multiple requests in parallel via Postman Newman to load test the API

Tags: node.js, api, postman, load-testing, newman

I'm not a Node.js developer but I installed Newman Postman just to be able to load test my API.

I want to take advantage of a simple idea suggested at the link below to run multiple API requests in parallel from a batch file. Source: https://community.getpostman.com/t/how-can-i-run-simultaneous-request-parallely/3797/2

Due to my lack of knowledge of Node.js console commands, I'm failing at running the script file. What's the right syntax to run this batch/text file with a list of Postman collections?

I tried:

As a developer at the link above suggested I created myfile.txt file and plugged in:

```
newman run c:\path...\collection.json -e c:\path...\staging.json &
newman run c:\path...\collection.json -e c:\path...\staging.json &
newman run c:\path...\collection.json -e c:\path...\staging.json
```

Then I ran the file with:

```
newman run c:\path...\myfile.txt
```

Fail.

Then tried running the file this way:

```
node c:\path...\myfile.txt
```

No luck.
Then I tried added `#!/bin/bash` inside of the file and running the same way but with .sh extension.
Still no luck.

How can I run my simultaneous api calls from the file here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The recommendations from the article you're referring are about [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), I don't know why you're talking about Node.js.
2. The recommendations from the article are all for **sequential** execution of multiple tests
3. You don't be able to apply any of these instructions because looking into `c:\` drive you seem to be using a Windows OS

---

If you want to kick off several parallel version of `newman` process (whatever it is) in a Windows [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) interpreter it makes sense to use [start](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) command like:

1. Create file `myfile.cmd`
2. Put the following lines there:

   ```
   start newman run c:\path...\collection.json -e c:\path...\staging.json 
   start newman run c:\path...\collection.json -e c:\path...\staging.json 
   start newman run c:\path...\collection.json -e c:\path...\staging.json
   ```

However I would rather recommend going for a specialized load testing tool, there is a variety of [free and open source load testing solutions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use/) which don't have any problems with parallel API tests execution and at the end of test you will get nice tables and charts as I fail to see how you're going to analyze the results of your "load test" with Postman/newman.

Comment: I agree here, Postman isn't a load testing tool, it was never designed to be. Many tools have been created for that sole purpose, you're going to get a much more targeted set of outcomes from those tools.

Comment: I was a bit surprised that the post says that the commands will run in parallel. I do see that they run sequentially when I just plug this code in console instead of executing them from a script file. Thought maybe it's something I don't know and they will in fact run in parallel when executed from a script file? Are you saying my assumption and the writer of that post were wrong? Will the commands in the file not run in parallel?

Also, a quick comment on why I tagged Node.js. It was required for Newman to run the test from Node.js console.

Comment: @DannyDainton the goal to run in parallel doesn't have to be for load testing. It could be as simple as run my tests faster and show me the results sooner.